# How do I display items from one database table under their associated categories from another database table (Laravel 5.4)?

Tags: php, mysql, database, controller, laravel-5.4

I am trying to display, in my view, topics from one database table underneath of the categories they belong to. The categories are being pulled from another database table but I have joined the two tables in my Controller. So far, I have successfully pulled the categories and displayed them all onto the screen. I am having an issue getting the correct topics to be displayed under the correct categories. Right now, all of the topics are being displayed under all of the categories. In other words, all ten categories have all thirty topics under them when each category should only have a few topics under them.

Here is the relevant code from my controller:

```
$topics_collect = collect();
$category_collect = collect();
$category_titles = collect(); 

$topics = DB::table('categories')
    ->join('topics', 'categories.id', '=', 'topics.category_id')
    ->select(
        'categories.*',
        'categories.title as categories_title',
        'topics.*',
        'topics.id as topic_id'
    )->get();

    $category = DB::table('categories')->get();

    foreach ($category as $item) {
        $category_titles->push($item);
    }

    foreach($topics as $topic){
        $topics_collect->push($topic);
    }

    foreach($category as $item){
        $category_collect->push($item);
    }

 return view('index', compact('category_titles', 'topics_collect', 'category_collect', 'category_collection', 'categories'));
```

And here is my view file (blade):

```
@if (!empty($category_collect))
@foreach ($category_titles as $item)
    <h3>{{ $item->title }}</h3>
        <div>
            <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
                @if (!empty($topics_collect))
                    @foreach ($topics_collect as $topic)
                        <li><a href="/topics/{!! $topic->id !!}">{{ $topic->title }}</a></li>
                    @endforeach
                @endif
            </ul>
       </div>
@endforeach
```

I have been using Laravel's documentation (https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers, https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent) but I am still having problems getting this to work.